# Java compiled with newer JDK does not run in older Java

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea, java-11, java-17

I wrote a fairly simple spring boot application in Java.  I am on Windows, using latest intelliJ, Maven, and JDK 17.  Have configured my compiler source and target to Java 11

My understanding is that I should be able to run this app in Java 11. But when I run in Java 11, I get error below:

> Error: LinkageError occurred while loading main class
> com.my.org.application.tester.Runner
> java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/springframework/boot/CommandLineRunner has been compiled by a more
> recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 61.0), this
> version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to
> 55.0

I tried using Java 11 to compile but get this error when I compile:

> org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
> execute goal
> org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile
> (default-compile) on project passport-tester: Compilation failure

I am consuming spring-boot-autoconfigure 3.0.0.  Have confirmed my jdk settings are correct.  When running in JDK 11 I have set JAVA_HOME, path, CLASSPATH to point to JDK11 folder

Is there any other setting I am missing, or should I check to make this work?

Comment: Your code and your code’s dependencies aren’t compiled with the same compiler (in general).

Comment: It looks like you're using Spring Boot 3, which AFAIK requires Java 17. It's the spring classes that are compiled for Java 17. Your own compiler settings don't affect this.

Comment: @JornVernee well that explains it, noob mistake, I thought I was good after seeing that Spring Boot 3 is backwards compatible with JDK 11 and 8 (https://www.marcobehler.com/guides/spring-and-spring-boot-versions#:~:text=What%20is%20the%20latest%20Spring%20Boot%20version%3F,2022%2C%20is%20Spring%20Boot%203.0.)... should have hit the docs

Comment: Look here: https://spring.io/blog/2022/11/24/spring-boot-3-0-goes-ga It lists "A Java 17 baseline". The blog you linked seems to be incorrect.

Comment: I strongly recommend to read for spring boot only the official blog.. The given blog is simply wrong.

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes :

> Spring Boot 3.0 requires Java 17 as a minimum version.